# get value by id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is used on a page for database hosting. The page has sliders from which a user selects the number of cores required and upper and lower limits of ram. The selected values from the slider are working and output in span id's. I then want to take the selected values to calculate a price. However I just cannot get back the value. I broke it down into simple parts and realise that there is no value being returned for cores or ram. What do I need to do to retrieve the values as and when the slider updates the page?

```
 <script>
    function showValues(event, ui) {
        var values;
        if (!ui.values) {
            values = $("#" + event.target.id).slider("values");
        } 
        else {
            values = ui.values;
        }
        if (values[0] == values[1]) {
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            values[0] % 1 == 0;
            values[1] % 1 == 0;
            $("#" + event.target.id + "-valuemin").html(parseInt(values[0]));
            $("#" + event.target.id + "-valuemax").html(parseInt(values[1])); 
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var base = 24;
        var cores = parseInt($("#CoreSlider-valuemin").val()*5);
        var ram = parseInt($("#RanSlider-valuemin").val()*2) + parseInt($("#RanSlider-valuemax").val());
        var cost = parseInt(base) + parseInt(cores) + parseInt(ram);                
        $("#Cost").html(parseInt(cost));
    });
$(function() {$( "#RanSlider" ).slider({range: true,min: 1,max: 64,step: 1,values: [4, 16],slide: showValues,create: showValues,change: showValues});});
$(function() {$( "#CoreSlider" ).slider({range: false,min: 1,max: 16,step: 1,values: [2],slide: showValues,create: showValues,change: showValues});});

    </script>
```

Comment: What value you're not getting? Show HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` is not a function that can get a text from an element (if it's not an input or something similar). `text()` can do it. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bandrzejczak/jdf1a2ct/

*Edit: Let me rephrase it: What you use to write stuff (like `.text("a")`, `.html("b")`), `.val("c")`, you can then use to read stuff from the same element, without using arguments (`.text("a")` to write and `.text()` to read)*

Additionaly if you want to count cost after every slider move, you should put the calculation function in your valueChange function.

Of course there is a much better way to do it, without using helper `div`s, but this one I could make work the fastest, with what you got.

*Edit: And don't use `parseInt` on what you know is an `int`, like `base` variable.*

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge seems to be on associating event processing with the slider.  Your existing code looks as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#RanSlider").slider(
    {
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 64,
        step: 1,
        values: [4, 16],
        slide: showValues,
        create: showValues,
        change: showValues
    });
});
```

Your code show options of `slide`, `create` and `change`.  Those are not valid options.  Instead, you would want to register event callbacks such as:

```
$("#RanSlider").on("slide", showValues);
$("#RanSlider").on("create", showValues);
$("#RanSlider").on("change", showValues);
```

or more efficiently:

```
$("#RanSlider").on(
{
    "slide": showValues,
    "create": showValues,
    "change": showValues
});
```